# AsyncRestTemplate.exchange equivalent in Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring

I would like to know if there's any equivalent to `AsyncRestTemplate.exchange` in Spring 3.2. Most of my application is written on Spring 3.2 and I want to make asynchronous calls to a web service. In Spring 4, we can use the `AsyncRestTemplate` to achieve this. What would be the way to do this in Spring 3.2?
Any help on this would be great!

Comment: Well it was introduced because there wasn't any. You would have to write your own implementation/extension for the `RestTemplate` using an async library.

Answer (score 0):

As @M. Deinum mentioned, writing own async code with Spring is easy. If you do something like this:

```
  @Async("customTaskExecutor")
  public Future<String> asyncRestTemplateCall(){
    return new AsyncResult<String>(restTemplate.exchange(...));
  }
```

Configuration for thread pool can look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public Executor customTaskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
  }
}
```

You have wrapped RestTemplate in async call and AsyncResult implements Java Feature.

EDIT:

Max mentioned in comments that this is not using event loop with non-blocking I/O as AsyncRestTemplate, but it delegates blocking call into separate thread.

Comment: Well, that will not work the way AsyncRestTemplate works, as your code will spawn new threads for these requests, while AsyncRestTemplate can leverage (by default?) Java NIO for that task.

Comment: @Max to help you find the code, please give me line number where NIO is used in AsyncRestTemplate code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.java

Comment: Sure, line 560. It uses AsyncRequestFactory, which allows integration with whatever NIO library you want. RestTemplate has no such facility.

Comment: Also, if you check the provided implementations of AsyncRequestFactory, at least one of them, Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory, works fully asynchronously using a nio event loop group.

Comment: @Max, I see. I updated my response. You are suggesting to implement this code based on Netty event loop? What's the problem with one separate thread that is dedicated to wait for HTTP call?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything. I just commented that `@Async` + `RestTemplate` does not cover full functionality of `AsyncRestTemplate`. And as the author of this question never specified why does he want AsyncRestTemplate in first place, I felt entitled to comment on the parts your solution does not cover. The difference is simple - given a heavy load on this application your solution would spawn N threads, which are **heavy on resources**. While AsyncRestTemplate can be configured to use a single thread for whatever amount of requests without any performance degradation.

Comment: The resources you are referring to are consumed when thread objects are created/destroyed. I used thread pool where threads are reused. So when you have I/O bound logic handled in well tuned thread pool (which this isn't), there isn't huge waste of resources.